# Add and change relative directory to an existed path (python script)

Tags: python

There is a default path in a function:

```
def function(directory):
path = ('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g')
newdirectory = (This is the part I am asking)
```

I call this function:

```
from xxx import function:
p('../../x/y')
```

I need to get a new directory 'newdirectory', which is supposed to be 'a/b/c/d/e/x/y', in order to proceed to the next step, but I don't know how to add the relative directory to an absolute directory and generate a new absolute directory

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()` to join the two path strings together, and `os.path.abspath()` to resolve the relative parts into one absolute path.

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g', '../../x/y'))
```